# R won't add Value and responds with +

Tags: r

I need some help with my R console. (Note that I am veeeery new to R and need to do this for an Uni project, so please explain for dummies!)
If I try to add values to a vector, it constantly wants to calculate something. I am not sure why, as it works for all my other values.. but my vector ANIMACY just will not work.
I have tried shortening values from "animate" to "ani" and "inanimate" into "inani", but that did not do the trick.
When I press the escape button, I am at least out of the calculation, but R won't add the values to my Vector.
With all my numeric and other character values, it works.

```
ANIMACY <-c("animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","inanimate","inanimate","inanimate","animate","animate","inanimate")
+ 
+ 
+ 
> PRONOUNS <- c("yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no")
```

Comment: You line is too long for the R interpreter. Try splitting it into 2 or 3 lines. Just hit enter somewhere around column 2549 after a comma should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

Not sure what exactly I did to fix this, but I collapsed the first variable to see where the error was. When I ran it after it seemed to work fine. Perhaps R has a limit what it reads from left to right...

```
ANIMACY <-
  c(
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "inanimate",
    "animate",
    "animate",
    "inanimate"
  )

PRONOUNS <- c("yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no")
```

It appears that may be the culprit due to what I found here. Can't say for certain:
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc

## Edit:

Looks like somebody did indicate above that is in fact the reason.

Comment: No prob! Glad to help. For your information, that command in R is `ctrl + shift + A`